# ngDialog.open event is creating new controllers?

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I have a link where user clicks to see details of some information. This click fires a ng-dialog open event, like:

```
 ngDialog.open({
  template: 'partials/acaoDetalhe.html',
  className: 'ngdialog-theme-default ngDialogSize',
  controller: MetaController,
  scope: $scope

});
```

and a listener so that when the dialog gets opened, the listener retrieves other informations of the MetaController.

```
$scope.$on('ngDialog.opened', function (e, $dialog) {
  console.log('ngDialog opened: ' + $dialog.attr('id'));
  $scope.$broadcast('getMetaCompletaEvent', $scope.meta.id);

});
```

It works fine the first time user clicks on the link. The functions of the controller are called and information is retrieved from backend. But after the user clicks outside the dialog window and click on the link again, the methods of the controller are called twice. If the user "closes" the dialog again and click again on the link, methods of the controller are called three times. It seems like the dialog remains hidden and every time user clicks on the link, a new dialog is opened and another controller is created. Why does it happen ? I need the other dialogs to really close after user clicks outside them.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Marcus after some issues with ngDialog, I switched to $modal component. The code is almost the same to open and close a modal instance and the modal does really closes my controllers after closing it.

Comment: In my case, I found that I was accidentally adding the listener on every opening and that´s why it fired x times (where x was the number of times I had clicked to open the dialog).

Comment: but it should fire only once at every opening, considering that the close event should really closes the previous dialog. If you click, open and then close, and then open again, this last opening event should fire the opening event only once.

Comment: Yes, but if you add the listener on every time you open the dialog you will increment the number of listeners and since you will be adding the same callback function it will fire 1 time for every time you have opened the dialog. The listener should be added outside the `ngDialog.open` function, which was not true in my case.

Comment: I got it. In my case, at the opening method, i was triggering a method which was responsible for load the new screen. This method was supposed to be called only once at every modal opening but was being called the number of opening events triggered. It was like the modal had not been closed, so I considered a component error and replaced it. Now it works fine.. but imagine the system becoming too much slow because of multiple method calls ...

Comment: @Marcus thanks for elaborating, adding additional callbacks each time the dialog was constructed ended up being the cause of the bug I was trying to fix.